# Is "of" instead of "have" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, orthography, auxiliary-verbs

I have noticed a lot of people use *of* instead of *have*, for example: "that must of been really annoying".  Is this correct?

Comment: I hope you don't mean that.  It could also be a sign of newness to English.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: I read *ear-literate* as an eggcorn of *illiterate…*

Comment: It will shock many to learn that the OED has an entry for the verb ‘of’. Its etymology is given as ‘variant of HAVE (verb), arising through misapprehension of the verb (when occurring as a clitic) as showing OF (prepostion)’ and it is described as non-standard. The entry has ten citations from 1814 to 1998, including one from the surely far from idiotic Charlotte Brontë.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ: Newness to English? Really? I learned English as a second language, and I don't think anyone who has painstakingly learnt "I should have" and "that must have" would make this particular mistake. Instead, I see this as a rather sure sign of a native English speaker.

Comment: I believe you, not knowing much about the subject myself - but I still think *idiot* is too strong a term. Even *lazy* could be unfounded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did the use of "could of" and "should of" originate, and is it considered correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48686/how-did-the-use-of-could-of-and-should-of-originate-and-is-it-considered-co)

Answer (score 37):

In speech, this is merely a relaxation of pronunciation - *should have* becomes *should've*, *must have* becomes *must've*.  This relaxed pronunciation is fine.

However, the contracted *have* (i.e. *-ve*) should not be written as *of*.  *Of* sounds similar to *-ve*, so many people erroneously think *should of* and *must of* is how to write *should've* and *must've*.  *Should of* and *must of* are improper.

Use *should have* and *must have* when you are writing, unless you are writing dialogue, or writing informally.  In those cases you also have the option of using the contractions *should've* and *must've*:

> That must have been really annoying.

Or, in dialogue and informal settings (e.g. chat):

> "That must've been really annoying!" said Jack.

Comment: Originally it must have been a "mere relaxation of pronunciation", but more recently I've heard people say "must of" etc. very clearly (i.e. the sound must be "of" and can't possibly be "'ve"). Misapprehension feeding back upon itself, I suppose...

Comment: It's a legitimate *spoken* clitic, just like shortening "I am going to go to the store" to "I'm'ina go to the store." It has no corresponding written form. It's usually pronounced like "must'a".

Comment: I think "of" and "'ve" are homonyms, so I don't see how one could "very clearly" say "must of" as Karl claims.

Comment: @KefSchecter, "of" has two (or more) common pronunciations depending on whether it's stressed or not. If it's stressed, it often sounds completely different from its unstressed form which is the homophone of "'ve". So perhaps that's what Karl meant, that the person clearly said the stressed pronunciation and thus likely meant "of". For example, US pronunciation of stressed vs unstressed: /ʌv/ vs /əv/, /ə/.