# What is the origin of the "should of" instead of "should have" mistake?

Tags: etymology, grammar, pronunciation, orthography, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did the use of “could of” and “should of” originate, and is it considered correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48686/how-did-the-use-of-could-of-and-should-of-originate-and-is-it-considered-co)

Recently, I tend to stumble a lot over the mistake that people write *should of* instead of *should have*:

> I should of done that.

I am trying to understand what the cause of this confusion between *have* and *of* could be. As from a grammatical point of view, I could not think of anything more different than a verb and a preposition. And when I read it, it doesn't even *sound* the same to me.

So I wonder, is it a regional thing? That somewhere 'have' and 'of' are pronounced the same way? Or is it mostly a common mistake of non-native writers?

Comment: The "origin" is a combination of imprecise hearing, poor understanding of grammar, and simple laziness of enunciation. No doubt it occurs everywhere English is spoken. Even the most careful speaker would see nothing wrong with saying, for example, *"I should've spoken more clearly"* in an informal context. ***He*** knows he said *"'ve"*, but it's impossible for anyone else to distinguish that from *"of"* by sound alone. I consider this General Reference/Not Constructive.

Comment: Same as [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48686/how-did-the-use-of-could-of-and-should-of-originate-and-is-it-considered-co).

Comment: I guess you should of used the search feature. OK, I'll see myself out now...

Comment: I think you may not be aware of the fact that "of" is the only English word in which "f" is pronouced as "v" (hence very different from "off"). Therefore, "ve" and "of" are in fact pronounced in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Many people learn this "mistake" at birth onward.  "Should've" becomes "should of" long before formal eduation.  It's actually, specifically, a mistake of native writers.