Is "under the weather" an adjective phrase?
I have known the meaning of "under the weather" since forever but it just now comes up to my mind the function of it in a sentence. Is it "adjective phrase" in a sentence?

It's a prepositional phrase, but of course its syntactic function depends on the sentence. What's the sentence?

A prepositional phrase can modify a noun or a verb (or sometimes other parts of speech). There's a lot of variation in exactly how phrases are named by different people/grammars (some seem to differentiate adjective and adjectival phrases!), so you need to be clearer what you're asking.

Though its meaning (literal and figurative) is different, both its form and the way it’s used are similar to those of on the prowl (searching for a sexual or romantic partner), off one’s rocker (insane), and many more prepositional phrases.

The helpful comments are off the charts!

@alphabet I've never heard it used literally as a prepositional phrase. It's an idiom that means "sick", and it functions like that adjective.

The terminology has sadly not been consistent over the years (and is probably still ambiguous). [a] 'adjectival phrase' has been used to label a phrase which behaves like an adjective, typically modifying a noun. He is a man with a mission. // [b] 'preposition[al] phrase' has been used to describe a phrase headed by a preposition.  He is a man with a mission. //// Most modern grammarians favour the formal (structural) labelling, [b].

Let me use an example sentence:

I felt under the weather.

Here, the phrase under the weather is not an adjective phrase (AdjP) but a preposition phrase (PP) serving as a predicative complement (PC).
According to H&P's CGEL, PCs are usually realized by AdjPs but they can also be realized by noun phases (NPs) (e.g., a fool in I felt a fool) and even PPs such as under the weather.
The phrase under the weather is straightforwardly a PP consisting of the preposition under and its complement the weather.
Traditional grammar argues that under the weather is an AdjP because it functions as a predicative complement. But the fact of the matter is, under the weather in I felt under the weather is no more an AdjP than a fool in I felt a fool.
Here's an excerpt from H&P's CGEL (p 530):

Seem, appear, etc., allow predicative PPs with idiomatic meanings, such as in a bad  temper, in good working order, in good shape, out of control, under the weather. But even  these are normally excluded by become and make: compare He seems in a bad temper;  *He became in a bad temper; *This made him in a bad temper.

(Boldface mine.)
EDIT
With respect to @DW256's claim that under the weather is an AdjP because it's 'gradable', CGEL's subsection Gradability not restricted to adjectives (p. 532) clearly indicates in the title itself that just because under the weather is gradable doesn't mean it must be an AdjP.
The subsection says: some adjectives and adverbs are gradable but others aren't; and some nouns and verbs can be gradable. Based on these observations, it concludes:

What distinguishes adjectives and adverbs from nouns and verbs, therefore, is not  that the former may take degree dependents while the latter may not. It is a matter of  the syntactic constructions used to express grading.

Another example of the subsection could be many, much, few, little, all of which are gradable and even inflect for grade but CGEL doesn't classify these as adjectives but determinatives (p. 393).
As for @DW256's claim that under the weather is an AdjP because it can take AdjP-only modifiers such as very and too, CGEL says (p. 533)

In general, PPs don’t take very and too as degree modifiers. Some of the idiomatic  PPs mentioned above as admissible complements of seem, etc., do allow them, but with much as an alternative construction: 
[17] i a. *It was [very before lunch]. b. *We placed it [too above the floor].
ii a. He’s [very (much) in the know]. b. He was [too (much) out of sorts to join in].


You have to be careful with "I felt a fool" - there are two constrictions. I went to the asylum and felt a fool and The seat of my pants ripped open and I felt a fool. In the first "a fool* is a direct object; in the second, it is the equivalent of "foolish" - an adjectival objective.

@Greybeard In your first example, isn't "a fool" describing "I"?

The distinction is between (i) an object and (ii) a complement. The second is, in fact, "like/as(prep) a fool."

@Greybeard What's the basis for the distinction?

It's debatable.
According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p528:

Central members of the adjective category have the cluster of
syntactic properties given in 1, where the adjectives in the
examples are all [bolded]:
1
i function
They can appear in three main functions: attributive (happy people),
predicative (They are happy), postpositive (someone happy).
ii gradability
They are gradable, and hence accept such degree modifiers as very,
too, enough, and have inflectional or analytic comparatives and
superlatives (happier, happiest, more useful, most useful).
iii dependents
They characteristically take adverbs as modifiers (remarkably happy,
surprisingly good).
No one of these properties is unique to adjectives, and many
adjectives do not have the full set of properties. However, words that
do have this combination of properties are clearly distinct from words
of other categories.

Under the weather can in fact be shown to have this combination of properties, at least for some English speakers.
Gradability

Some women particularly will have felt more under the weather than they should have been. (The Journal)
In all of your years singing, what would you say is the most under
the weather you’ve ever been on a night when you’ve had to perform?
How did you overcome that adversity and push through the evening; and
what do you remember feeling after you walked off stage?
(Interview)
Sleep is very important as well as eating, no matter how under the weather you feel. (Winnebago County, Julia Salomon, MS, RDN )

Also, it can be modified by very/pretty/too/enough:

He insisted the TalkTV show 'must go on’ despite the Uncensored host
feeling very under the weather. He will do his duties from home,
meaning a very different look for the programme later on.
(Mirror)
Marie's pretty under the weather for the next couple of days. (Longman)
If you need to get your hands on some aspirin, but you’re feeling too under the weather to make it to your local pharmacy, we’ve got the answer for you. (Healthera)
You won’t win a Juno or an Oscar for these performances — after all, most parents aren’t doctors and have soft spots for their offspring — but hopefully you can fool them into thinking you’re sick enough to stay home, but not quite under the weather enough to warrant a trip to the doctor’s office. (Canadian HR Reporter)

Function
It does occasionally occur as pre-head modifier in noun phrases, a position which typically excludes prepositional phrases.

The treats in this brightly decorated gift will be sure to help
under-the-weather kids get well. (Boston Gift Baskets)

One major point against the AdjP analysis is that it does not occur in complex-transitive constructions with verbs that exclude locatives, but does occur in transitive locative constructions with verbs that exclude predicative complements.

It made me ill.
*It made me under the weather.
*It put me ill.
It put me under the weather.
e.g. Friday was Muniz’s first race back in the cockpit after an illness. A parasite put him under the weather for nearly a month this summer, but Muniz said he’s feeling better now. (mlive)

However, it does occur in a fairly wide range of complex-intransitives as a predicative.

*He seemed under the house.
Tux the cat seemed under the weather, so his owner, Palash Pandey, decided to take her to a vet near his home in Austin. (Merriam-Webster example sentence)
*You became under the house.
Our team at AFC Urgent Care Ooltewah is here to help your family stay healthy! Exercise is one way to prevent illness, but if you or a member of the family become under the weather, don’t hesitate to visit us. (AFC)

And of course it can occur as a postpositive.

Yakomin’s plea prompted aficionados to share a slew of heartfelt
memories — many of which noted that it’s the ultimate comfort food, as
well as a cure-all for anyone under the weather. (NY Post)

Dependents
It can be modified by adverbs, but then so can prepositional phrases, so that's not much of an indication one way or the other.

But it seems whether people are feeling especially under the
weather is a matter of opinion. (CTV News)

Conclusion
As an idiom, considering the criteria assigned to adjectives by CGEL, it sure does appear to be moving towards an AdjP classification, at least for some English speakers.

No, it's not debatable. None of your points in favor of the AdjP analysis proves that it's an AdjP. All they prove is that the PP can function as a predicative complement (as in your first, second and last points) and as a pre-head modifier (as in your third). True, PPs typically don't behave this way. But under the weather is not a typical PP. It's a predicative PP with an idiomatic meaning.

Also, put him under the weather sounds to me as bad as, if not worse than, made him under the weather. The former has only two pages on Google, whereas the latter only one page. And become under the weather, which CGEL says is ungrammatical (see the last paragraph of my answer), has only five pages on Google. None of the three expressions appears on COCA.

Cf. The only answer to this question Is "of" instead of "have" correct? has 37 votes and the answer is "No". https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43256/is-of-instead-of-have-correct But Google has no less than 18 pages for "should of done". And COCA has 10 hits.

@JK2 I'm presenting evidence in favor of the AdjP argument. You haven't addressed the facts that it's gradable and that it takes AdjP-only modifiers. CGEL claiming things to be ungrammatical is fine and all, but there's evidence out there that these uses exist, and in order to explain them, an AdjP analysis is not all that far fetched, there already being other compound adjectives allowed by CGEL that have no adjectives in them, p1660 4.3.3 "This is an area where it is difficult to draw a clear line between syntax and morphology, but it may be best to treat them as compound adjectives."

Right before that quote comes this sentence "Such expressions are typically nonce-forms, restricted to attributive modifier function." There is not a single example of a PP being reclassified as an AdjP in CGEL, AKAIK.

You haven't addressed the facts that it's gradable and that it takes AdjP-only modifiers. ==> I've addressed these issues in my answer as an EDIT.

@JK2 Fair enough, though with all those exceptions being made for a very special type of PP, it would seem easier just to admit that analyzing it as an AdjP would simplify things greatly. Also, that gradability discussion does not touch upon PPs so that's neither here nor there. I'm honestly not entirely convinced of either explanation; it's  an idiom that either: (A) behaves very much like an AdjP with some small exceptions, or (B) is a very peculiar PP that needs lots of special exceptions to explain how people use it.

No, it's you who are making exceptions. The principle in CGEL and other modern grammars is that phrase types (such as a PP and AdjP) are determined solely by the part of speech of the head. But you're trying to make an exception to the principle by saying the phrase type of under the weather is an AdjP purely for some functional reasons. If you go that way, it gets really messy because you don't know where to draw the line. How idiomatic a PP should be to be reanalyzed as an AdjP is an open question.

-1 for citing only CaGEL to claim something that it does not endorse. What's the point of listing CaGEL's properties of adjectives when the book unequivocally classes "under the weather" as a PP?

@listeneva Looks like I got under some people's skin here. All I did was apply CGEL's criteria to this idiom. If the results don't line up with something they claimed, then it's up to the critical reader to decide what to make of it. CGEL's solid gold most of the time, but that doesn't mean it's infallible or not worth questioning.

@DW256 You must have completely misunderstood CaGEL's criteria, which starts with Central members of the adjective category have the cluster of syntactic properties given in 1, where the adjectives in the examples are all. Here, CaGEL is only discussing a part of speech (i.e., adjective), which is a classification of a word (NOT a phrase such as "under the weather"). Traditional grammar have attempted to class phrases and even clauses into part-of-speech categories based on their function. But CaGEL clearly objects to those attempts throughout the book.

@listeneva I understand quite well CaGEL's criteria and system of word vs phrase classification. My argument was that, being an idiom, one could consider it as an adjective under-the-weather (without analyzing its internal structure) and then go on to apply the criteria to see whether such an analysis would produce acceptable results. I provided data that says it might. CaGEL in its Lexical word-formation section admits of compound adjectives, nouns, etc. that if analyzed internally would not appear to be adjective or noun phrases.

@listeneva CGEL p643 "We have seen that there are a number of idiomatic PPs that are gradable, and as far as their external syntax is concerned they bear significant resemblances to adjectives" How far does that resemblance have to go before they are considered as such? It's an open question in my opinion: the exceptions that have to be made to still classify these as straight-up PPs seem excessive.

@DW256 By the boldfaced portion CaGEL means that their syntactic function resembles that of adjectives. That's why they're still called PPs, not AdjPs. I'm afraid you're conflating the very two concepts which CaGEL went to great pains not to conflate: 'syntactic function' and 'syntactic category'.

@listeneva Read the lexical word formation part of CaGEL and then carefully consider my previous comments and answer. You can interpret CaGEL however you like, this is my take on it.

@DW256 What is the lexical word formation part of CaGEL? Give me the chapter and section number or page number.
